# Can I go ski in Innsbruck at the end of November, beginning of December?

Tags: austria, skiing

I'm planning to go to Innsbruck for the weekend of 30th November - 2nd December.

However I'm not sure if the ski runs will have enough snow. Or at least the most beautiful ones.

In particular, I was thinking of going to the Axamer Lizum resort. But I'm interested in all of them.

Can you give me some tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately from the [Axamer Lizum webcam](http://www.axamer-lizum.at/en/index.php?Ski_resort%3aWebcams) there's already snow base, and they're making snow too. In addition, it's at altitude, so there's an added advantage for colder temperatures.

However the start of the season is always weather dependent, and there it's usually mid/late November.  So it all depends on which runs you want to do, and luck, and how late you can leave your trip.  Best you can do is keep an eye on the snow report and weather on [their website](http://www.axamer-lizum.at/en/index.php?Ski_resort%3aWeather) and keep any eye on the webcams as well.  Their lift page should also start to indicate which runs are open as they get enough of a base.

You can also check out the [climate for Innsbruck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innsbruck#Climate) and note the snowfall for that time of year.  Check out weather sites too and see if there's snow falling on the long rage forecasts.  It should give you a decent idea.

Finally you can check on instagram or flickr or other photo sharing sites when it opens.  If people are taking GPS-tagged photos, you can get an idea of the view from their shots and how beautiful different runs might be.

Comment: Thanks for all tips. I have a flight on 30th November. According to what you say, it is quite safe to expect good snow on that day. (I have to buy the flight this week) Correct ?

Comment: Not quite. I'm saying the season is unpredictable, but usually starts mid-late November.  However, from my experience working on a ski resort in Colorado, that doesn't mean all the runs will be open - it all depends on the snow.  That's why I linked to the weather and snow reports - it's worth watching/reading them.  [The latest snow reports](http://www.j2ski.com/snow_forecast/Austria/Axamer_Lizum_snow.html) are forecasting 4-17cm of snow this weekend, so that's a good sign at least! But nothing's guaranteed, such is the nature of outdoor activities.

Answer (score 5):

Right now there is a little snow in the resort. Moreover, there are snow canons. Thus, odds are good that you will have snow and that you will be able to ski. However, you can never be sure. Weather conditions in the Alps can be capricious. The little snow can melt away, and when you arrive, the canons cannot be used, or there are bas conditions, such as snow storms or fog, ... Sounds good. Doesn't it? But that can happen at any time of the season.

If you stay in Innsbruck, you have the option to go to the Stubaier Gletscher. This resort is open and skiable all the year, unless there is a storm or too much fog.